# How to open .dbf table exported from ArcMap 10.7 with Access 2013 or later Microsoft Office versions?

Tags: arcmap, ms-access, dbf, reports, arcgis-10.7

I have exported an attribute table as .dbf file with ArcMap 10.7 but if I try to link it to an Access 2013 database (it works fine with Access 2007) I get a message error  "Could not find installable ISAM".

It happens with any .dbf files and on different computers. Only Access 2007 seems to work.

I am not too happy with the embedded reporting tool on ArcMap and would like to extract the table and use the features on the newer Microsoft Access to then print a report.

Is there any other ways I can extract the attribute table and link it to a newer version (not 2007) of Microsoft Access database?

Comment: Have you tried exporting to a personal geodatabase (*.mdb), should work with access

Comment: This isn't an ArcGIS question so much as an Access one -- The dBase format used by Esri remains unchanged, but Microsoft stopped supporting dBase-III+.

Comment: I have Access 2010 and 2016 on my computers and I can import or link to a dBase file in both under the External Data's More drop down.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the ['Table to Excel'](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-excel.htm) tool, Access will happily use that format and this tool give you more option (like exporting alias as field name or choosing between code or description for domain)

Take care of the number of row limitation :

> The input cannot exceed the 65535 rows limit of the .xls file format